# C++ Alternative to templatized data member

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, containers, c++03

If I have a class `DataManager`:

```
class DataManager
{
 public:
   int getRecordInt( size_t i ) const;
   std::string getRecordString( size_t i ) const;

 private:
   std::vector<int> _vInt;
   std::vector<std::string> _vString;
}
```

I can access records with e.g.

```
DataManager DM;
// .. populate object ...
int iValue = DM.getRecordInt(3);
```

In my real application, I will have over a hundred data types (besides int and std::string), so I would like to avoid having to write a separate getter for each of the types.

Now, if C++ would support templatized variable names (which it does not), I could implement the class as:

```
class DataManager
{
 public:
   template<typename T>
   T getRecord( size_t i ) const
   {
      return _v<T>[i];
   }

 private:
   std::vector<int> _v<int>;
   std::vector<std::string> _v<std::string>;
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve the purpose in C++?

(Please be aware that although I have simplified the example to the bare minimum, my real-world problem is much more complex and calls for the existence of such `DataManager` class.)

Comment: With the second hypothetical implementation of class DataManager, I could then simply call `int iValue = DM.getRecord<int>(3);`. I hope the idea I am after is clear.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. it falls under the category of reflection, which is not supported yet.

Comment: what do you mean with "templatized variable names"? In your last code the member  `_v` is `std::vector<int>` independent of how `getRecord` is called and its not clear what you mean with `_v<int>` in the declaration

Answer (score 4):

### C++14 Solution:

One thing you could do is put all the different vectors into a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).  Then you could use [`std::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) to specify which vector to get from the tuple and then access that vector.  That would look like

```
class DataManager
{
 public:
   template<typename T>
   T getRecord( size_t i ) const
   {
      return std::get<std::vector<T>>(_v)[i];
   }

 private:
   std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string>> _v{{1,2,3},{"a","b","c"}};
};

int main()
{
    DataManager d;
    std::cout << d.getRecord<std::string>(2);
}
```

Which outputs

```
c
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2dc27aa6f08cc3f)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. That is what I am after, but unfortunately I can only use C++03 in the project (forgot to mention it in the question), and that version of std::get() seems to have been introduced in C++14.
Any ideas in C++03?

Comment: @user7065361 If you cannot use C++11/14 then I think Serge Ballesta's answer is they way you would have to do it.  Or you could use `boost`, which has `boost::tuple`.

Comment: I am afraid that with tuple its not possible to hold 'over a hundred data types'

Answer (score 2):

If your types appear only once, you can use `std::tuple` and `std::get`:

```
class DataManager
{
public:
   template<typename T>
   T getRecord( size_t i ) const
   {
      return std::get<std::vector<T>>(v)[i];
   }

 private:
   std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::string>> v;
}
```

Comment: Same answer I wrote to Nathan: thank you, your solution is what I am after, but unfortunately I can only use C++03 in the project (forgot to mention it in the question), and that version of std::get() seems to have been introduced in C++14.
Any ideas in C++03?

Comment: If you have C++03, then you have access to `tuple` and `type_traits`, which are all it is needed for implementing `get<type>`, it is is relatively easy, in fact I'm pretty sure I saw once an implementation example in cppreference.com. Even if not, I did [implement `get<type>`](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/artifact/df1800b71e34a70c) as part of my backports library for C++ taking directly from the proposal that was lifted for C++14.  You might be able to use the code as a basis.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a templatized variable, but you can have a private templatized method that return the appropriate variable:

```
class DataManager
{
 public:
   template<typename T>
   T getRecord( size_t i ) const
   {
      return _v<T>()[i];
   }

 private:
   std::vector<int> _vInt;
   std::vector<std::string> _vString;
   template<typename T> std::vector<T>& _v() {
       throw std::logic_error("non managed type");
   }
};

template <> std::vector<int>& DataManager::_v<int>() {
   return _vInt;
}
template <> std::vector<std::string>& DataManager::_v<std::string>() {
   return _vString;
}
```

It is up to you to say whether it is an acceptable solution for your real use case.

Comment: Just curious why you're throwing an exception instead of using  `static_assert`.  Since the call will be resolved at compile time wouldn't an "error" be better?

Comment: Is writing a separate template specialization for each type easier than writing a separate getter?

Comment: @NathanOliver: probably a Java (wrong here) usage... and I am to lazy to build the `std::if` that it would require. Fill free to edit my answer with it if you want.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: it can depend on the actual use case. That's the reason for my last sentence...

Comment: @NathanOliver: And C++03 doesn't have `static_assert` :-)

Comment: Thank you Serge, this will do!
For my application, I need to call `getRecord<T>()` from another template function so plain getters were not an option, since they would not have allowed me to pass the type.

Answer (score 0):

If [Serge Ballesta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45328127/27678) doesn't float your boat (and IMHO it's the proper way to proceed), then you can grit your teeth and write a macro (C++03 solution):

```
#define ADD_RECORD_TYPE(TYPENAME, QUALIFIED_TYPENAME) \
private: \
    std::vector<QUALIFIED_TYPENAME> _v##TYPENAME; \
public:  \
    QUALIFIED_TYPENAME get_record_##TYPENAME(size_t i) const{return _v##TYPENAME.at(i);}

class DataManager
{
    ADD_RECORD_TYPE(string, std::string)
    ADD_RECORD_TYPE(int, int)
};
#undef ADD_RECORD_TYPE
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xLZfVRyCROsER2KD)